# Read with one thread, send datas to another thread

Tags: multithreading, qt, file

Im working with threads. In the following code, i read datas from txt and run it on my thread. I want to use another thread for writing the datas another txt file. How can i do it?

```
#include "mythread.h"
#include <QtCore>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QFile>
MyThread::MyThread()
{

}

void MyThread::run()  //Reading file from txt with thread1
{
    QFile file("C:/Users/ilknu/Documents/untitled1/deneme.txt");

    if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        QTextStream in (&file);
        while (!in.atEnd())
        {

            QString line = in.readLine();
            QStringList list = line.split(QLatin1Char(' '), Qt::SkipEmptyParts);
            for(const QString &entry : list)
            {
                double num = entry.toDouble();
                qDebug()<<num;
                queue.enqueue(num);

            } // for
        } // while
    } // if

    file.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should subclass `QObject` then use this subclassed object to run your program in another thread. Use `Qt's` `Qt::QueuedConnection` (it's the default if the connection is between two threads) to communicate between two threads. And don't forget to use `QMutex` when accessing same data from two different threads.

Your `MyThread` class might look like:

mythread.h

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QMutex>

class MyThread : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyThread(QObject* parent = nullptr);
    ~MyThread();

signals:
    void writingDone(); // This signal is for main thread

public slots:
    void writeData(); // Slot to ask the thread to write data
};
```

mythread.cpp

```
#include "mythread.h"
MyThread::MyThread(QObject* parent)
    : QObject(parent)
{
    // Initialize the variables and call the functions you need
}

MyThread::~MyThread()
{
}

void MyThread::writeData()
{
    // Use this function to write data to a file
    // This function will run in a different thread
    // emit the signal when/if required
    emit writingDone();
}

// Add other functions if needed
```

In the subclasses `QMainWindow` you need to create a new object of `MyThread` and then move it to a new thread. You can do it as follows:

mainwindow.h

```
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include <QThread>
#include "mythread.h"
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR);

private:
    Ui::MainWindowClass UI;
    MyThread* myThreadObject; // Create a object of MyThread
    QThread* myQThread; // Create an object of QThread

signals:
    void startWriting();

public slots:
    void writingDoneByThread();
};
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);

    // Initialize the new objects
    myThreadObject = new MyThread();
    myQThread = new QThread();

    // Move to new thread
    myThreadObject->moveToThread(myQThread);

    // connect signal and slots
    connect(this, &MainWindow::startWriting, myThreadObject, &MyThread::writeData);
    connect(myThreadObject, &MyThread::writingDone, this, &MainWindow::writingDoneByThread);

    // Start the new thread
    myQThread->start();
}
```

After this the function `MyThread::writeData()` will run in a new thread. The connect between the main thread and the other thread is the default `Qt::QueuedConnection` and so you don't have to worry about how the connection is made. Just keep in mind to use `QMutex` if you are accessing data from a different thread. You can add many more functions and variables to the `MyThread` class and use it as a normal `QObject` subclass.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll try it immediately

Comment: I get some errors in mainwindow.cpp

1) ... Documents\MyThread\mainwindow.cpp:2: error: ui_mainwindow.h: No such file or directory

2) ...Documents\MyThread\mythread.cpp:18: error: type 'QObject' is not a direct base of 'MyThread'

Comment: 1) If you are using MS Visual Studio then this error will disappear after a while.. 2) This error seems unknown, I would suggest adding #include <QThread> to mythread.h file.

Comment: Im using QT Creator , im still couldnt solve these error, i will try. Thank you

Comment: Hi, how can i start my program in main. cpp??

Comment: I do not understand, in main.cpp you just create an instance of your `QMainWindow` subclass and show it, but it is done by the QT creator already so I am guessing you are talking about something else?